# html5 javascript- How to catch attempt to initiate navigation out of sandboxed iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sandbox

I have an sandboxed iframe that doesn't allow changing location:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts" class="iframe visible" src="thesource.html" width="100%" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

If the iframe tries to unframe itself or change location I see a blank page because the browser stops the iframe's operation. This is the log from Chrome:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL 'http://example.com' from frame with URL 'http://otherdomaian.com'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the 'allow-top-navigation' flag is not set.

That is great but I want to catch this so if it happens I'll move to the next iframe. So how do I catch this attempt?

**EDIT:**

I added a [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/62xfT/) (check the error in the console log)

I also tried to listen for an event with no success:

```
document.addEventListener('error', receiveMessage, true);
function receiveMessage(error) {
    alert("iframe tried to unframe itself");
}
```

Comment: Does this include the case where someone clicks a link and it has a target set to `_parent` or `_top`?

Answer (score 13):

I am new here so I don't have enough reputation to comment on answers and I apologize if I am doing this wrong, but the accepted solution will unfortunately not be able to accomplish what you are looking for.

I was able to demonstrate what I mean by having the script from the JSFiddle above run once the DOM is ready (there will be no alert but still an error in the console). Here's a little more detail on what happens currently with that fiddle:

```
// running with the No wrap - in <head> option
var frame = document.querySelector('iframe'); // null, the iframe isn't there yet
try {
    frame.src="http://wedesignthemes.com/themes/redirect.php?theme=wedding";
} catch(e) {
    // TypeError here, no hints about the iframe :(
    alert('Error!');
}
```

The exception that is being caught has nothing to do with the iframe, it is actually a type error from trying to set the `src` property on a `null` value.

What you really want to do is catch the error *inside* of the iframe (when the sandboxed script tries to access `window.top`), but this is not possible because of the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). Btw, setting the `"allow-same-origin"` sandbox flag only has any effect when the iframe content is being served from the same `origin` as the top level document. E.g. as soon as the `src` or `location` of the iframe is changed to a different `origin`, [there's no way to touch anything inside](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/iframe.html).

There are ways to communicate across `iframe` boundaries, such as with `window.postMessage` or the older and hackier way of using the iframe's `location.hash`, but I am assuming you can't affect the source of the page going into your iframe. (A nice developer would of course be open to suggestions and see that a feature like this could be useful.)

The only way that I was able to catch this error without violating any browser security policies was to set the `allow-top-navigation` sandbox flag and then use the `window.onbeforeunload` handler in the top level document to catch the navigation attempt from the child `iframe`. I would never recommend this because the user experience is **awful**. There is no way to prevent the navigation without prompting the user about whether they want to leave the page or not. Proof of concept below:

```
<iframe id="myframe" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"></iframe>
<script>
  var url = "http://wedesignthemes.com/themes/redirect.php?theme=wedding",
      frame = document.getElementById("myframe"),
      listener;
  listener = window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      // The iframe tried to bust out!
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", listener);
      return "This is unavoidable, you cannot shortcut a " +
             "navigation attempt without prompting the user";
  });
  frame.src = url;
</script>
```

So unfortunately I can't find any ways to do this nicely in current browser implementations without help from your 3rd party content developer. I read some interesting things in the HTML5 spec that might allow us to do things like this in the future (and am unfortunately maxed out on my number of links I can insert here), so I would keep an eye out as things progress.

Comment: Very nice writeup. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer with big red flags so people don't use it. Thank you for catching this and pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Example:

An  with extra restrictions:

```
<iframe src="demo_iframe_sandbox.htm" sandbox=""></iframe>
```

the sandbox attribute is supported in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.

> Note: The sandbox attribute is not supported in Internet Explorer 9
>   and earlier versions, or in Opera.

Definition and Usage

> If specified as an empty string (sandbox=""), the sandbox attribute
>   enables a set of extra restrictions for the content in the inline
>   frame.
>
> The value of the sandbox attribute can either be an empty string (all
>   the restrictions is applied), or a space-separated list of pre-defined
>   values that will REMOVE particular restrictions.

Differences Between HTML 4.01 and HTML5

> The sandbox attribute is new in HTML5.

Syntax

```
<iframe sandbox="value">
```

Attribute Values

1. "" => Applies all restrictions below
2. allow-same-origin => Allows the iframe content to be treated as being from the same origin as the containing document
3. allow-top-navigation =>  Allows the iframe content to navigate (load) content from the containing document
4. allow-forms =>   Allows form submission
5. allow-scripts => Allows script execution

javascript: is a kind of weird URI protocol. It works in some contexts, like , but not all - for instance, a window's location can not be set to such a URI. (While you can assign a javascript: URI to window.location as a really roundabout way of running a script, the window's location doesn't stay set to that value.)

To write content into an IFRAME, get a reference to the frame's document and write to it. Doing so will require that you set the allow-same-origin sandbox flag.

```
<iframe id="myframe" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

---

```
<script>
    var frame = document.getElementById("myframe");
    var fdoc = frame.contentDocument;

    fdoc.write("Hello world"); // or whatever
</script>
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/wUvrF/1/

Answer (score -1):

You can now do this with `allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation`